# Nifi ListS3 processor not returning full path for files stored in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I am using the `ListS3` processor to get files from `S3` and piping it into the `RouteOnAttribute` processor. From there I am using the `Route to Property name` as the `Routing Strategy` and assigning properties bases on which files I am listening.

I am able to see all the files I want but can't do anything with them because my another processor down the line needs the `full path` of those files. I am using a python script, that takes in `file path` as cmd line arguments.

How do I extract the full absolute path of the files from `S3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list, download, and save S3 files locally using a sequence of NiFi processors like the following:

1. **ListS3** - to get references to S3 objects you can filter.  Output from ListS3 contains only references to objects, not the content itself, in attributes:

   - *s3.bucket* - name of the bucket, like `my-bucket`
   - *filename* - key of the object, like `path/to/file.txt`
2. **FetchS3Object** - to download object content from S3 using the bucket and key from ListS3 above.
3. **PutFile** - to store the file locally.  Specify the `Directory` property where you want the files to be placed `/path/to/directory`.  The *filename* attributes from S3 will contain relative paths from S3 keys, so these would be added to the `Directory` by default.

You can then assemble local paths for your Python script using NiFi expression language:

```
/path/to/directory/${filename}
```

Comment: So, can I still use it as a python script cmd line args? something like `python myscript.py -file "s3://${s3.bucket}/${filename}"` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it to define arguments for `ExecuteStreamCommand` running a Python script.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something here, my python script keeps throwing me `file not found` errors. Are you sure I don't have to use `PutFile` or something like that to store the s3 files locally first?

Comment: Yes, to download the files from S3, you would need something like that.  I'll edit the answer.